# how to acces mini uart on a raspberry pi 0?

Tags: pi-zero, uart

I would want to be able to access the serial console and have an extra serial port so is there any way to access the mini uart with the gpio since its not being used for bluetooth. I'm using a raspberry pi 0 (not w).

Answer (score 2):

No.

I think both UARTs are connected to the same pair of GPIO (14 and 15).  That being the case you can only use one at a time.